# Polluting an image with Gaussian anisotropic noise and estimate the covariance matrix

Tags: parameter-estimation, noise

Assume that we have a $d\times d$ grey-scale image represented as a vector 
$$
\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_D)^T\in[0,255]^D,
$$
where $D=d\times d$. We would like to import some noise concerning the image's position, in order to create a new noisy image represented by the vector $\mathbf{x}'=(x_1',\ldots,x_D')^T\in[0,255]^D$.

**First question**: What could be that noise? Ideally, I would like that noise to be an anisotropic $D$-dimensional Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$. How could we pollute this image with this kind of noise?

**Second question**: Could we estimate the covariance matrix given the two representations?

**EDIT**:
Assume that $\mathbf{x}$ is the mean vector of the Gaussian and $\mathbf{x}'$ is some point drawn from this Gaussian. We want to express $\mathbf{x}'$ using $\mathbf{x}$ and the Covariance matrix $\Sigma$, while after that we want to estimate the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ using $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: For #1 this may be of use: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/mvnrnd.html

Comment: Thanks @lemon, but this is not what I want. I need to know the mechanism we introduce the noise. Think of $\mathbf{x}$ as the mean of the Gaussian and $\mathbf{x}'$ as a point drawn from the Gaussian. What is the relation?